Can a class contain a blank function that can be loaded via a method?
Currently, I am writing a code for scientific computation. I want to make a class of the MHD_Model, like so:
class MHD_Model{
    private:
    double position;
    double boundary_condidtion;
    double magnetic_field;
    public:
    // constructor, methods for setting the boundary condititon etc.
}

For now, double magnetic_field; is a number, however I need to make it a function of position. I imagine it this way, first I define the magnetic field like e.g.:
double Bfield(double x){
    return x*x;
}

and then write a method called double MHD_Model::load_magnetic_field() which will take a function Bfield as input. However, I can't make it work, and I started to suspect this isn't the right way to do so.
I am not a programmer by training but a physicist. I need to learn C++/other fast programming language as I started a PhD now and will be dealing with computation-heavy stuff.
I tried writing the function Bfield as pass by reference, pass by value, and using const double position within the class, but nothing compiles. I understand the errors (most of them are kind of like: binary operator / can't be used for types double and (double *) double). The main problem is that I don't know the "correct" way of writing such behaviour, and I am not sure if that's allowed the way I imagined the program to be structured.
Can someone suggest anything or point me to a resource on this? I know the best way would be to learn C++, but I am short on time.
BTW, my supervisor is not programming either, so I can't refer to him; he's only using Wolfram Mathematica.

EDIT:
I'm including what I programmed so far on how I imagine it would work:
main.cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <print>

#include "mhd.hpp"

using namespace std;

double b(double *x){
  return 1./ &x;
}


int main(){

  double q = 10.;
  double x = .3;
  MHDModel model;
  model.set_equipartition(q);
  model.set_position(x);
  model.load_magnetic_field(&b);

  return 0;

}

mhd.cpp
#include "mhd.hpp"

#include <iostream>



void MHDModel::set_equipartition(double q) {
  equipartition = q;
  std::cout << "Setting equipartition parameter to " << q << "...\n";
};

void MHDModel::set_position(double x){
  jet_position=x;
};

void MHDModel::load_magnetic_field(double b){
  jet_mag_field = b;
};

mhd.hpp
#ifndef MHD_HPP
#define MHD_HPP

#include <iostream>

class MHDModel{
  private:
    double jet_position;
    double jet_mag_field;
    double equipartition;
  public:
    MHDModel(double x = 0., double q = 1.){
      jet_position = x;
      equipartition = q;
      std::cout << "Creating magnetohydrodynamic model..." << "\n";
    };
  void set_equipartition(double q);
  void set_position(double x);
  void load_magnetic_field(double b);
};

#endif // !MHD_HPP

While I am aware that it shouldn't work, I have no idea how it would be done. It's kind of hard to research that, as everything concerning "load function into class" etc is about methods, which is kind of not the case here (I think?).

Welcome to Stackoverflow. Not clear what you mean by a "blank" function, or what is meant by "loading" it. I think you are simply saying that you want to the class MHDModel to have a method double magnetic_field()
that returns the value of some function of the model's position field. Is that right?

OT: Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>? And What's the problem with "using namespace std;"? Also please don't fall into a cargo cult, by copy-pasting code you don't really understand (in relation to that header).

Thank you! What I mean is that I want a method that takes a function as a parameter and stores this function within a class. The reason is that I want to use several different magnetic field functions magnethic_field that I would later on integrate numerically. The reason of not programming e.g. three different magnetic_field() methods is that I need my code to eventually work for user-supplemented magnetic_field. I do not want the magnetic_field() method to return a value specifically, I want it to be an internal function that is utilized later on.

Maybe instead of passing in a function, you might want to model the magnetic field as a class. If other users require precomputations or similar, a single function might not be enough. In that case, you should look up the "strategy pattern" and "dependency injection" which allow you to modify behavior based on a common interface.

You can have a member std::function that you can assign different things to and then call. Maybe that's what you are looking for...

Side note: please read Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>? and What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?.

Yes you can use a std::function to inject a function into your model like this :
// #include <bits/stdc++.h> <== NEVER include this... it is not standard C++
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

// do NOT use `using namespace std;`

double b(double x) // No need to pass double as a pointer
{
    std::cout << "b called\n";
    return 1.0 / x;
}


class Model
{
public:
    Model(std::function<double(double)> fn) :
        m_fn{ fn }
    {

    }

    double calculate(double v)
    {
        return m_fn(v);
    }

private:
    std::function<double(double)> m_fn;
};

int main()
{
    Model model{ b };
    model.calculate(1.0);
}

I use std::function because that allows you to inject lambda expressions with
captures too.

use can use a function pointer in the argument of your load_magnetic_field method
double MHD_Model::load_magnetic_field(double (*func)(double *x)) {
    double x = 1.0;
    return func(&x); // Call the function using the pointer
}

and then if you want to store such pointer withing the class
private:
    double (*stored_function)(double *x);

and to assign a pointer during a method call
stored_function = func;

we can also declare a function type to avoid having a full declaration in every use of it
typedef double (*FuncType)(double *x);

or in modern style
using FuncType = double (*)(double *x);

in that case the class member will look like that
private:
 FuncType stored_function;

and passing in argument looks like that
load_magnetic_field(FuncType func)


In addition to setting a function pointer or std::function at run time, there are several other ways to achieve your desired result. No one is absolutely better or worse than any of the others, choose one that works better in your particular settings. Here's a couple:


template <auto MagneticFieldFunction>
class MHD_Model { ...
}; 

...

MHDModel<b> myModel;



class MHD_Model {
  ...
  virtual double magnetic_field(double) = 0;
}

class Squares_MHD_Model : public MHD_Model {
  double magnetic_field(double x) final override {
    return x*x;
  }
}

...

Squares_MHD_Model myModel;



These versions are potentially ever so slightly more efficient than the ones that use function pointers or std::function, but also are potentialy more restrictive, depending on how exactly you plan to use your model objects.
